# Alternate query using if statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run an alternate query if the initial query fails (it does because the `id` I'm searching for in this instance only exists in one of the databases being joined) using an if statement  and I've constructed it like so:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/link_costreport_2013.php');
$id = $_GET['id']; //ID # For page/query
if($query = $link->prepare("SELECT locale.id, locale.provider_num, locale.provider_name, locale.state, locale.city,
                        finstat_ca.coh_and_banks, finstat_ca.temp_investments, finstat_ca.notes_receivable, finstat_ca.accounts_receivable, finstat_ca.other_receivables,
                        finstat_ca.afun_and_ar, finstat_ca.inventory, finstat_ca.prepaid_expenses, (finstat_ca.other_cur_assets + finstat_ca.due_from_other_funds) as other_cur_assets, finstat_ca.total_current_assets,
                        finstat_fa.total_fixed_assets,
                        finstat_olta.investments, (finstat_olta.dep_on_leases + finstat_olta.due_from_owners_officers + finstat_olta.other_assets) as all_olta, finstat_olta.total_other_assets, finstat_olta.end_assets,
                        finstat_cl.accounts_payable, finstat_cl.salaries_wages_fees_payable, finstat_cl.payroll_taxes_payable, finstat_cl.notes_loans_payable, finstat_cl.deferred_income, finstat_cl.total_current_liabilities,
                        (finstat_cl.total_current_liabilities - (finstat_cl.accounts_payable + finstat_cl.salaries_wages_fees_payable + finstat_cl.payroll_taxes_payable + finstat_cl.notes_loans_payable + finstat_cl.deferred_income)) as all_other_cl,
                        finstat_ltl.mortgage_payable, finstat_ltl.notes_payable, finstat_ltl.unsecured_loans, finstat_ltl.other_long_term_liabilities, finstat_ltl.total_long_term_liabilities,
                        finstat_talfb.total_fund_balance, finstat_talfb.total_lia_plus_fb
                        FROM `locale`
                        INNER JOIN `finstat_ca`
                        ON locale.id = finstat_ca.id
                        INNER JOIN `finstat_fa`
                        ON locale.id = finstat_fa.id
                        INNER JOIN `finstat_olta`
                        ON locale.id = finstat_olta.id
                        INNER JOIN `finstat_cl`
                        ON locale.id = finstat_cl.id
                        INNER JOIN `finstat_ltl`
                        ON locale.id = finstat_ltl.id
                        INNER JOIN `finstat_talfb`
                        ON locale.id = finstat_talfb.id
                        WHERE locale.id = :id
                        LIMIT 1")){

} else {
$query = $link->prepare("SELECT id, provider_num, provider_name, state, city
                        FROM `locale`
                        WHERE id = :id
                        LIMIT 1");
}
$query->bindParam(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($results);
```

Basically it defaults to the single table where the ID does exist and only pulls a couple fields as opposed to the large statement above it. My only issue is that my code here is not working. My JSON only says `false` when I echo it. It obviously should not.

Is there an error in my code here?

Thanks in advance

:edit: I should note that when I enter an ID that exists in all the tables joined, the correct result (json) is displayed on the page.

Comment: Prepare doesn't execute the query, it just sets it up.  You should adjust your logic to check the results of the query and requery with a different statement if the first fails.

Comment: So how do I test if the query is going to return false, which it does in this instance.

Comment: Test $results, if it is false, use the second query.  You could prepare two statements, try the first and if it returns false, use the second.

Comment: @user2182349 - Got it, the answer was to use `if($link->query()){}` Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that even if ID does not exist in the first query, the $query variable still has a proper query in it and there is nothing false about it.   That's not what you should be if-testing.
I think you should be testing $results.

This shows you the logic.

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php/link_costreport_2013.php');
//ID # For page/query
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql_1 = "SQL CODE FOR QUERY 1";
$sql_2 = "SQL CODE FOR QUERY 2";

$query = $link->prepare($sql_1);
$query->bindParam(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$results)
{
    $query = $link->prepare($sql_2);
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

However as you can see there are a few lines of code that are repeated inside the if-statement that very similar to code that was just before the if-statement.   Perhaps with a loop that loops twice but breaks out if $results is not false would be neater.

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php/link_costreport_2013.php');
//ID # For page/query
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql[] = "SQL CODE FOR QUERY 1";
$sql[] = "SQL CODE FOR QUERY 2";

foreach ($sql as $sql_query)
{
    $query = $link->prepare($sql_query);
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($results)
    {
        break;
    }
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

The world is your oyster.